# Chart with Apexcharts JS and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, apexcharts

I try to make a heatmap chart with Apexchars and PHP; I take the values from Mysql database.

The values on the x axis (console.log(ora)) :
1 dec,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,2 dec,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,3 dec,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23

The values on the y axis for 1m (console.log(d1)):
22,77,91,33,16,31,78,61,22,22,7,81,13,23,4,17,24,92,13,2,46,46,4,89,84,84,69,89,95,37,53,28,56,65,89,6,1,21,15,71,88,77,86,93,52,13,87,25,22,82,78,13,42,74,38,14,2,140,9,7,139,54,8,32,38,33,58,5,58,78,72,33

The values on the y axis for 2m (console.log(d2)):
21,71,28,57,2,54,84,22,92,54,89,89,31,15,9,4,3,42,66,96,3,26,2,9,69,46,87,96,33,35,54,281,49,48,12,67,23,66,95,18,18,33,75,99,86,4,150,56,1,69,54,5,22,26,37,56,45,139,29,65,138,1,37,41,15,77,31,99,14,69,27,97

My code:

```
   <?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  include 'connection.php';
  //$select_days=$_GET["select_specie"];
  $select_specie="1,2,3";
  $numetb = 'current_direction_2017_dec';
  $sqlQuery = 'SELECT `Hour`, `Depth1m`, `Depth2m` FROM `'.$numetb.'` WHERE `Day` in ('.$select_days.')';
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlQuery) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: - Error: ".mysqli_error($conn), E_USER_ERROR);
  $hour1=[];
  $depth1=[];
  $depth2=[];
  while($rel=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $hour1[]=$rel['Hour'];
  $depth1[]=$rel['Depth1m'];
  $depth2[]=$rel['Depth2m'];
   }
  $hour1=implode(',',$hour1);
  $depth1=implode(',',$depth1);
  $depth2=implode(',',$depth2);
   mysqli_close($conn);
   ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
   <title>Grafic cu Apexcharts JS + PHP + MySQL</title>
   <style>
    #chart {
      max-width: 650px;
      margin: 35px auto;
     }
    * {
      font-family: Arial;
      }
     body {
     height: 100vh;
     background: #f9f9f9;
      }
      #chart, .chart-box {
       padding-top: 20px;
       padding-left: 10px;
       background: #fff;
       border: 1px solid #ddd;
       box-shadow: 0 22px 35px -16px rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
     }
    .apexcharts-canvas {
      margin: 0 auto;
     }
    #html {
      display: none;
     }
     </style>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
     </script>
     </head>
      <body>
     <div id="chart"></div>
     <script>
       var ora = <?php echo json_encode($hour1);?>;
        var d1 = <?php echo json_encode($depth1);?>;
        var d2 = <?php echo json_encode($depth2);?>;
       console.log(ora);
       console.log(d1);
       console.log(d2);
        var options = {
             series: [
              {
                name: "1m",
                data: [{
                       x: ora,
                       y: d1
                  }]
              },
                {
                name: "2m",
                data: [{
                        x: ora,
                        y: d2
                 }]
               }
               ],
             chart: {
               height: 350,
               type: 'heatmap',
               },
              dataLabels: {
               enabled: false
                },
               title: {
                text: 'Apexchart - Heatmap',
                },
                colors: ["#008FFB"]

                 };
                   var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
                   chart.render();
                </script>

                </body>
                   </html>
```

The values are not displayed correctly on the chart; only 2 values are shown: 21 and 22.
The labels from x-axis in not correctly.
Should I use xaxis?

If I want to add interactivity to the chart, for example the user to choose the days from a select tag, and the value to send with post / get to the variable $select_days, would it be difficult ?

I look forward to any ideas/advice.

Comment: Try changing x: ora, to x: [ora] and same for d1 and d2.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I solve the issue with this: data: [<?= $depth1 ?>]; xaxis : { categories: [<?= $hour1 ?>]}